# Can I return rows result from db without scan it first in Golang func?

Tags: sql, go

I have mini project using Golang, my plan is make a base function which it will be called from Model to execute sql query, then return the rows result without Scan it first. I'm using this way to prevent forget write `defer rows.Close()` and the code for execute the Query in model more simple. I had tried this way, but when try to print the result, I got nil without any error. here my screenshoot. The result exists when the query executed and the rows result scanned are in same function. Maybe I miss something? This is my first question, sorry it's too long. Thank you

[The base model where the SQL query will be executed and return the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnWFM.png)

```
package model

import "database/sql"
import "hb-backend-v1/config/database"
import "fmt"

func Query(query string) (*sql.Rows, error){
    connect, err := database.Connect()

    if err != nil{
        fmt.Println("Connection Failed")
        return nil, err
    }
    fmt.Println("Connection Success")
    defer connect.Close()

    rows, err := connect.Query(query)

    defer rows.Close()
    if err != nil{
        return nil, err
    }

    return rows, nil
}
```

[This is where the base model will be called and give the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNPDa.png)

```
package product

import "database/sql"
import _"fmt"
import "hb-backend=v1/model"

type Hasil struct{
    Id_alamat_store int
    Id_tk           int
    Alamat          string
    Id_wil          int
    Latitude        sql.NullString
    Longitude       sql.NullString
    
}

func ProductList() ([]Hasil, error){
    rows, err := model.Query("SELECT * FROM alamat_store")
    if err != nil{
        return nil, err
    }
    
    var result []Hasil
    for rows.Next(){
        var each = Hasil{}
        var err = rows.Scan(&each.Id_alamat_store, &each.Id_tk, &each.Alamat, &each.Id_wil, &each.Latitude, &each.Longitude)
        if err != nil{
            return nil, err
        }
        result = append(result, each)
    }
    return result, nil
}
```

Comment: I'm not allowed yet to embed image to my first question, so they include it with link instead, sorry

Comment: Ohh sorry, I have added it

Comment: nit-pick: Field names like `Id_alamat_store` are not commonly seen in golang code. In go, names should be `CamelCased` (or `camelCased` for non-exported names). Quite a few linters will complain about those fields. Check the [code review comments](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments) for details

Comment: Oke thank you, I note it. I'm new in golang so I still need learn and practice more

Comment: NP. We've all had to start out somewhere. There's a lot of examples and information scattered all over the web, so if you don't know where to look, it's easy to pick up bad habits, or following along with an outdated source. Just thought it best to let you know that there is a resource that lists some conventions that are very widely adopted

Comment: Okey thank you, it's really helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `connection` and `rows` will be closed once `Query` exits, after those two are closed you can't use `rows` anymore.

One approach to get around that would be to pass a closure to `Query` and have `Query` execute it before closing the two resources:

```golang
func Query(query string, scan func(*sql.Rows) error) error {
    connect, err := database.Connect()
    if err != nil{
        return err
    }
    defer connect.Close()

    rows, err := connect.Query(query)
    if err != nil{
        return err
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    return scan(rows)
}
```

```golang
func ProductList() ([]Hasil, error) {
    var result []Hasil
    err := model.Query("SELECT * FROM alamat_store", func(rows *sql.Rows) error {
        for rows.Next() {
            var each = Hasil{}
            var err = rows.Scan(&each.Id_alamat_store, &each.Id_tk, &each.Alamat, &each.Id_wil, &each.Latitude, &each.Longitude)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            result = append(result, each)
        }
        return nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return result, nil
}
```